# No apt_pkg and black screen after installing Python version

Tags: boot, apt, python

I was having some trouble installing things due to a python library not being found. I don't remember exactly, but I may have installed a different python version.

Now on start up my screen is black and has a blinking cursor. In recovery mode the option repair broken packages says the following:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'apt_pkg'.

How do I proceed?

Ubuntu 22.04
Python 3.10 -> 3.7(?)

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop systems very much rely on python3, and it **must** be the version the system came with, so changing the **default** version will cause many desktop apps & package problems (eg. inability to use `apt` & other front-end tools; though some base apps like `wget` or `dpkg` will still work).  That is **expected** behavior.  You didn't specify if desktop or server, but if you changed the default python3 version, what you describe is expected; undo your changes.  FYI:  If you change default python3, text terminal should still work, even if you've lost your GUI (*until changes reverted*)